# unir 2 vetores (a[10], b[10]) em um vetor c[20]

Tags: c

Como faço para unir dois vetores A[10] e B[10], para criar um vetor C com 20 elementos.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(){

    int a[10];
    int b[10];
    int c[20];
    int i;

    srand(time(NULL));

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        a[i] = rand()%101;
    }
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        b[i] = rand()%101;
    }
    for(i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        c[i] = rand()%101;
    }

    printf("%d\n" a[i]);
    printf("%d\n" b[i]);
    printf("%d\n" c[i]);
}
```

por enquanto estou tentando imprimir os 3 mas ja esta dando erro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em vez de usar um terceiro loop para montar a união dos vetores, é possível obter o mesmo resultado com `memcpy`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    int a[10];
    int b[10];
    int c[20];
    int i;

    srand(time(NULL));

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        a[i] = rand()%101;
    }
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        b[i] = rand()%101;
    }

    // Montagem de c
    memcpy(c, a, 10 * sizeof (int));
    memcpy(c + 10, b, 10 * sizeof (int));

    // Exibição dos resultados
    for(i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        printf("%d\n", c[i]);
    }

}
```

O primeiro argumento do `memcpy` é um ponteiro para o destino (portanto para a 1a posição de `c` no meu primeiro uso e 11a posição no segundo uso. O segundo é ponteiro para a origem, e o terceiro é o tamanho do dado que você quer copiar.

[Veja funcionando no Ideone](https://ideone.com/kN56Wu).

Answer (score 0):

Você até chegou perto na sua tentativa, mas na hora de copiar para o vetor `c`, você não pegou o valor dos outros vetores, e sim gerou outro aleatoriamente.

Ali no laço que preenche o `c`, você deveria ter feito uma condicional, se for menor que 10, pega do `a`, senão pega do `b`, só calculando a posição do vetor onde está pegando e pra onde vai.

Esse cálculo está na resposta do CiroboyBR, e outra opção seria:

https://ideone.com/KdvYYZ

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef int vint10[10];
typedef int vint20[20];

int main(void) {
    vint10 a, b;
    vint20 c;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        a[i] = rand() % 100;
        b[i] = rand() % 100;
        printf("a[%02d]=%2d, b[%02d]=%2d\n", i, a[i], i, b[i]);
    }
    printf("---\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        c[i] = i < 10 ? a[i] : b[i-10];
        printf("c[%02d]=%2d\n", i, c[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{

int i, a[10], b[10], c[20];

srand(time(NULL));

for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    a[i] = rand()%20;
    b[i] = rand()%20;
}

for(i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
    c[i] = a[i];
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
    c[i+10] = b[i];

printf("\nA: ");
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
    printf("%d ", a[i]);

printf("\nB: ");
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
    printf("%d ", b[i]);

printf("\nC: ");
for(i = 0; i < 20; i++ )
    printf("%d ", c[i]);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: rodando no ideone https://ideone.com/4lb41V